# How to implement a dynamic form with controlled components in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-component

As I am looking at the examples in the reference for `controlled form components` [in react.js official website](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), I am wondering how is one supposed to implement a `form` in which you would be able to `remove` and `add` `input` elements dynamically in such a way that they are controlled components? Is this even possible?

In the examples we can see:

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Due to the nature of my work, I often find myself having to implement such forms. Moreover, I don't `add` or `remove` `input` elements directly - I am managing custom components, but for the sake of simplicity here I am asking for basic form elements.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

> How adding/removing input elements dynamically possible?

Yes, it is possible, you can add/remove `input` elements `dynamically`, But for that you need to take care of few things:

**1-** Proper binding of events.

**2-** Array to store the values of each input element separately.

**3-** When user fill value in any input element then updating only that specific value in state.

**Logic:**

Maintain an array inside state, that will store the values. Use **[#array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** to create ui (input element) for each array values. while creating the fields, use a remove `button` with each field, and pass the index of field in that `function`, it will help you to identify which field you wants to delete, do the same thing for `onChange` also.

Check this example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { values: [] };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  createUI(){
     return this.state.values.map((el, i) => 
         <div key={i}>
         <input type="text" value={el||''} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, i)} />
         <input type='button' value='remove' onClick={this.removeClick.bind(this, i)}/>
         </div>          
     )
  }

  handleChange(i, event) {
     let values = [...this.state.values];
     values[i] = event.target.value;
     this.setState({ values });
  }
  
  addClick(){
    this.setState(prevState => ({ values: [...prevState.values, '']}))
  }
  
  removeClick(i){
     let values = [...this.state.values];
     values.splice(i,1);
     this.setState({ values });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.values.join(', '));
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          {this.createUI()}        
          <input type='button' value='add more' onClick={this.addClick.bind(this)}/>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='container'/>
```

Check the working `jsfiddle`: https://jsfiddle.net/mayankshukla5031/ezdxg224/

Comment: If I needed the add more to render a textbox + a checkbox, how would this code change?

Comment: @jaimish11 you should ask a separate question based on this code, instead.

Answer (score 12):

> How adding/removing input elements dynamically with functional components?

The same component from the selected answer reviewed and rewrited as a functional component.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';

function DynamicInput() {

    const [values, setValues] = useState({ val: []});

      function createInputs() {
        return values.val.map((el, i) =>
          <div key={i}>
            <input type="text" value={el||''} onChange={handleChange.bind(i)} />
            <input type='button' value='remove' name={i} onClick={removeClick.bind(i)} />
          </div>
        );
      }

    function handleChange(event) {
      let vals = [...values.val];
      vals[this] = event.target.value;
      setValues({ val: vals });
    }

    const addClick = () => {
      setValues({ val: [...values.val, '']})
    }

    const removeClick = (event) => {
      let vals = [...values.val];
      let index = Number(event.target.name);
      vals.splice(index, 1);
      setValues({ val: vals });
    }

    const handleSubmit = event => {
      alert('A name was submitted: ' + values.val.join(', '));
      event.preventDefault();
    }

    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          {createInputs()}
          <input type='button' value='add more' onClick={addClick} />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );

}

export default DynamicInput;
```

Comment: I am defining everything exactly as you mentioned in your answer, but this woudn't work if we have two inputs generated with the `addClick` method, the values will be the same in both inputs. do you know how to solve it?

This is how `jsx` look like
`<div key={index}>
<input type='text' value={el||''} onChange={supply_detail_handler.bind(index)}/>
<input value={el||''} onChange={supply_detail_handler.bind(index)} type='number'/>
</div>`

Comment: Don't get it, ask a new question with proper details and post here the link, I'll try to solve it ;)

Comment: I asked new question with the code here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60132525/how-to-create-and-store-values-of-a-dynamic-form-reactjs .Thanks in advanced

Comment: i know this is two years old, but i am trying to do the same thing here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73779422/form-handle-array-as-input-react where i have implemted this selution but i am missing something to connect it .. hope you maybe can help me..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an object because you have many input field
**you can do this** :

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { values: [] };
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
```

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { values: [{question: '',response: ''}] };
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    
     createUI(){
       return this.state.values.map((el, i) => 
           <div key={i}>
              <input type="text" value={el.question}  onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, i)} />
              <textarea type="text"  value={el.response} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, i)} />
              <input type='button' value='remove' onClick={this.removeClick.bind(this, i)}/>
           </div>          
       )
    }
     handleChange (i,event) {
       let values = [...this.state.values];
       values[i][event.target.id] =   event.target.value;
       this.setState({ values }); 
    }
    
    addClick(){
      this.setState(prevState => ({ values: [...prevState.values, {question: '',response: '',}]}))
    }
    
    removeClick(i){
       let values = [...this.state.values];
       values.splice(i,1);
       this.setState({ values });
    }
    
    handleSubmit(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert(this.state.values.map(objet=> "{"+ "  "  + "'question' :" + "  " + objet.question + "  " + "'response' :" + "  " + objet.response +"  " + "}") );
    }
     render() {
      return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            {this.createUI()}        
            <input type='button' value='add more' onClick={this.addClick.bind(this)}/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      );
    }
  }
  
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
              <input type="text"  value={el.response} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, i)}  id="response" a />
          
         <input type='button' value='remove' onClick={this.removeClick.bind(this, i)}/>
        
         
       </div>
      
       )
    }
  
    handleChange (i,event) {
       let values = [...this.state.values];
       values[i][event.target.id] =   event.target.value;
       this.setState({ values }); 
    }
    
    addClick(){
      this.setState(prevState => ({ values: [...prevState.values, {question: '',response: '',}]}))
    }
    
    removeClick(i){
       let values = [...this.state.values];
       values.splice(i,1);
       this.setState({ values });
    }
  
    handleSubmit(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert(this.state.values.map(objet=> "{"+ "  "  + "'question' :" + "  " + objet.question + "  " + "'response' :" + "  " + objet.response +"  " + "}") );
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            {this.createUI()}   
            <div  className="d-flex justify-content-end">
              <KamaminiButton onClick={this.addClick.bind(this)}  text='Ajouter une autre question' />
            </div>     
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      );
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```
<div id='container'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe to have found a much simpler way to do this by using the useRef() hook. You simply keep a reference to the form which has the variable number of inputs, and use a button for adding and removing inputs. Then on submit, you use the childNodes() function to get all the values.

form.js:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react'

const Form = () => {
  const formRef = useRef(null)
  const [numInputs, setNumInputs] = useState(1)

  const submitHandler = () => {
    let inputs = formRef.current.childNodes
    for (let i = 0; i < numInputs; i++) {
      console.log(inputs[i].value)
    }
  }

  return (
    <form ref={formRef}>
      {Array.from(Array(numInputs)).map((_, i) => (
        <input type="text" />
      ))}
    </form>
    <button onClick={() => setNumInputs(numInputs - 1)}>Remove input</button>
    <button onClick={() => setNumInputs(numInputs + 1)}>Add input</button>
    <button onClick={submitHandler}>Submit</button>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use your state or the props that you are passing from other components to decide what your form should be.

Here a dumb example:

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    let myForm;
    if(this.props.someprop == true){
       myForm = (
           <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <label>
                 Name:
                 <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange=      {this.handleChange} />
              </label>
              <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
           </form>
       );
    }
    else if(this.state.statevar == "expectedValue"){
        myForm = (
           // other HTML with embedded JS here
        );
    }


    return (
         {myForm}
    );
  }
}
```

I did it in the render method just to be clear but all the logic can be moved in auxiliary functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component, } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
var childJson = []
export default class AddInvoice extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        Json: [],
        rows: [{}]
    }
}

handleChange = idx => e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const rows = [...this.state.rows];
    rows[idx] = { [name]: value };
    this.setState({ rows });

    console.log(`rows-->>${this.state.rows[idx].amount}`);
    childJson.push(this.dynamicJson(this.state.rows, idx))
    this.setState({ Json: childJson })

};
handleAddRow = () => {
    const item = {
        name: "",
        mobile: "",
        btn: ""
    };
    this.setState({
        rows: [...this.state.rows, item]
    });
};
handleRemoveRow = (idx) => {
    this.state.rows.splice(idx, 1);
    this.setState({ rows: this.state.rows });
};
dynamicJson(rows, index) {
    return {
        "service": rows[index].text,
        "tax": rows[index].tax,
        "amount": rows[index].amount
    }
};
render() {
    return (
        <div className="ui one column grid">
            <div className=" row">
                <div className="one wide computer one wide tablet one wide mobile column">
                </div>
                <div className="fourteen wide computer fourteen wide tablet fourteen wide mobile column">
                    <h1 id="title_header">INVOICE-ADD NEW</h1>
                </div>
                <div className="one wide computer one wide tablet one wide mobile column">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className=" row">
                <div className="one wide computer one wide tablet one wide mobile column">
                </div>
                <div className="fourteen wide computer fourteen wide tablet fourteen wide mobile column">
                    <div id="#cus_segment" className="ui segment" style={{ backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5' }}>
                        <div className="ui form">
                            <div className="ui  stackable grid">
                                <div className="six wide column">
                                    <div className="field">
                                        <label>Invoice No</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="invoiceno" placeholder="Invoice No" value={this.state.invoiceno} onChange={e => this.setState({ invoiceno: e.target.value })} />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className=" six wide column">
                                    <div className="field">
                                        <label>Customer</label>
                                        <select className="ui fluid selection search dropdown" name="customer" value={this.state.customer} onChange={e => this.setState({ customer: e.target.value })}>
                                            <option defaultValue="">select</option>
                                            <option value="sohanpatil@gmail.com">sohanpatil@gmail.com</option>
                                            <option value="mayurawati@gmail.co">mayurawati@gmail.com</option>
                                            <option value="nasirpatel@gmail.com">nasirpatel@gmail.com</option>
                                            <option value="nandkishorshinde@gmail.com">nandkishorshinde@gmail.com</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="one row">
                                    <div className="six wide column">
                                        <div className="field">
                                            <label>Invoice Date</label>
                                            <div className="ui calendar" id="calender1">
                                                <div className="ui input right icon">
                                                    <i className="calendar icon"></i>
                                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Invoice Date" value={this.state.invoicedate} onBlur={e => this.setState({ invoicedate: e.target.value })} />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="six wide column">
                                        <div className="field">
                                            <label>Due Date</label>
                                            <div className="ui calendar" id="calender2">
                                                <div className="ui input right icon">
                                                    <i className="calendar icon"></i>
                                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Due Date" value={this.state.duedate} onBlur={e => this.setState({ duedate: e.target.value })} />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="two row">
                                    <div className="six wide column">
                                        <div className="field">
                                            <label>Header</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="header" placeholder="Header" value={this.state.header} onChange={e => this.setState({ header: e.target.value })} />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="six wide column">
                                        <div className="field">
                                            <label>Remark</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="remark" placeholder="Remark" value={this.state.remark} onChange={e => this.setState({ remark: e.target.value })} />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="three row">
                                    <div className="ten wide column">
                                        <button className="ui primary button" type="submit">Save</button>
                                        <button className="ui  button" type="submit">Clear</button>
                                        <button className="ui  button" type="submit">Cancel</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div className="foure row">
                                    <div className="one wide column">
                                        <div className="field">
                                            <h4 style={{ textAlign: "center", borderRadius: 2 }}>Action</h4>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="two wide column" style={{ marginLeft: 55 }}>
                                        <div className="field">
                                            <h4 style={{ textAlign: "center", borderRadius: 2 }}>Text</h4>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="three column" style={{ marginLeft: 200 }}>
                                        <div className="field">
                                            <h4 style={{ textAlign: "center", borderRadius: 2 }}>Tax</h4>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="foure wide column" style={{ marginLeft: 190 }}>
                                        <div className="field">
                                            <h4 style={{ textAlign: "center", borderRadius: 2 }}>Amount</h4>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                {this.state.rows.map((item, idx) => (
                                    <div className="five row" id="addr0" key={idx} >
                                        <div className="one wide column">
                                            <div className="field">
                                                <div className="ui icon" style={{ backgroundColor: "#f76060", color: "white", height: 35, width: 40, textAlign: "center", borderRadius: 2 }} onClick={() => this.handleRemoveRow(idx)}>
                                                    <i className="trash alternate icon" style={{ marginTop: 8 }}></i>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div className="five wide column">
                                            <div className="field">
                                                <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="text" value={this.state.rows[idx].text} onChange={this.handleChange(idx)} />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div className="three wide column">
                                            <div className="field">
                                                <select className="ui fluid selection search dropdown " name="tax" id="tax_dropdown" value={this.state.rows[idx].tax} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}>
                                                    <option defaultValue="">Select</option>
                                                    <option value="STAX">STAX</option>
                                                    <option value="VAT">VAT</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div className="three wide column">
                                            <div className="field">
                                                <input type="text" name="amount" placeholder="amount" value={this.state.rows[idx].amount} onChange={this.handleChange(idx)} />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                ))}
                                <div className="six row">
                                    <div className="two wide column">
                                        <div className="field">
                                            <div className="ui icon" style={{ backgroundColor: "#c4d3d3", height: 35, width: 55, textAlign: "center", borderRadius: 2 }} onClick={this.handleAddRow}>
                                                <i className="plus icon" style={{ marginTop: 8 }}></i>
                                                <label>Add</label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="one wide computer one wide tablet one wide mobile column">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    );
}
```

}

Comment: working Example of Dynamic added Components and delete component at given index position