# ReactJS Get values inside dynamic multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops, object

I have done the dynamic inputs now my problem is getting the values of each inputs but its a multiple inputs? how can I achieve this. here is the jsfiddle.

```
 perRow() {
        return this.state.values.map((el,i) => 

                <tr key={i}>

                    <td className="col-md-4">
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Name" value={el||''} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, i)}/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Hourly Rate" />
                        </div>                        
                        <p><strong>Total hours:</strong> 0:00</p>
                        <p><strong>Total pay:</strong> $0.00</p> 
                            <button className="btn btn-danger do-not-print" onClick={this.removeClick.bind(this, i)}>Remove employee</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>Monday</td>
                    <td><input type="text" className="form-control" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" className="form-control" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" className="form-control" /></td>
                    <td>0:00</td>
                    <td>$0.00</td>
                </tr>

        )
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zd208m1a/2/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=zd208m1a

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dynamic input elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42316604/how-to-implement-a-dynamic-form-with-controlled-components-in-react-js)

Comment: dynamic but single elements. I want help for dynamic multiple input elements

Comment: [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lsruuec3/), let me know if you have any doubt :)

Comment: @MayankShukla Cool! Thanks a lot! Appreciate your help! Yeah I'm missing something!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can get your input values like `this.state.values.join(', ')`

since you got your input values in state values as as array

```
 handleChange(i, event) {
            let values = [...this.state.values];
            values[i] = event.target.value;
            this.setState({ values });
            console.log(this.state.values)
        }
```

Checck the below example , this will help you for sure [Demo done by mayankshukla](https://jsfiddle.net/mayankshukla5031/ezdxg224/)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, create `constructor` and we will create an onChange function so we need to bind it inside the constructor

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        username: '',
        password: '',
    };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
}
```

Then we need to create `onChange` function it will handle by the name

```
onChange(e){
        this.setState({ [e.target.name] : e.target.value });
    }
```

Finally, call the onChange function with a name attribute, you need to define the input name in the state to avoid any troubles.

```
<td><input type="text" className="form-control" name="username" onChange={this.onChange} /></td>

<td><input type="text" className="form-control" name="password" onChange={this.onChange} /></td>
```

2_ **Alternative way instead of binding the `onChange` function in the constructor you can use an anonymous arrow function like so**

```
onChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name] : e.target.value });
    }
```

3_ **Another Alternative way, you can bind it like so**

```
onChange(e){
   this.setState({ [e.target.name] : e.target.value });
}       

<input 
    type="text" 
    name="username" 
    onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} 
/>
```

4_ **Another Alternative way with passing data**

```
onChange(e,data){
console.log(data); // result is "something"
   this.setState({ [e.target.name] : e.target.value });
}       

<input 
    type="text" 
    name="username" 
    onChange={(e)=>this.onChange(e, 'something')} 
/>
```

Comment: Please look at my jsfiddle. my problem is on the state i will have multiple username and password

Comment: Do you mean you have two problems? the above answer will let you able to create multi inputs depending on the input attribute name

Comment: yeah I but in my problem is that it is dynamic. Example: in one row I have input for username and password then when I click the button add row I will have another input of username and password. In my current code I have solved the adding of rows of inputs now my problem is getting the values in each object array.

Comment: Okay, I understand you now, you just want to keep the previous data and add new data. Do am right? like [ 'PrevData', 'NewDate', 'NewNew' ]

Answer (score 0):

Here are the implement using react hook, hope this helps, too.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState([])

const handleChange = (i, event) => {
 let values = [...value];
 values[i] = e.target.value;

 setValue(values)
 console.log(values)
}
```

Step to get value inside multiple input text :

1. Create state with empty element array.
2. When onChange is runiing...
3. Copy `value` state into variable mutable. Example in es6 `let values = [...value]`
4. When `e.target.value` is getting done
5. Based on index total, `value` is saved inside `values` variable
6. Then, save final `values` inside `value` using `setValue`