# How to dynamically generate pair of input fields using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have tried the following code to create a react form to dynamically generate input fields to enter the series of person's name one by one. But user needs to enter the `first name` and `last name` instead of just `name`. So that, the form needs to generate pair of dynamic input fields. I am new to `react`. Can anyone please give an hint on how to accomplish this.

Note : The following code has been taken from the stackoverflow answer of @Mayank Shukla at [How to implement a dynamic form with controlled components in React.JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42316604/how-to-implement-a-dynamic-form-with-controlled-components-in-react-js).

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { values: [] };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  createUI(){
     return this.state.values.map((el, i) => 
         <div key={i}>
            <input type="text" value={el||''} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, i)} />
            <input type='button' value='remove' onClick={this.removeClick.bind(this, i)}/>
         </div>          
     )
  }

  handleChange(i, event) {
     let values = [...this.state.values];
     values[i] = event.target.value;
     this.setState({ values });
  }

  addClick(){
    this.setState(prevState => ({ values: [...prevState.values, '']}))
  }

  removeClick(i){
     let values = [...this.state.values];
     values.splice(i,1);
     this.setState({ values });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.values.join(', '));
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          {this.createUI()}        
          <input type='button' value='add more' onClick={this.addClick.bind(this)}/>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Idea is, maintain an array of object in state variable. Each object will have two keys `firstName` and `secondName` (you can add more fields). Treat each object as a single unit and for all the keys render input element, and whenever user will click on add more, add one more object/entry the the array with two keys.

[Working Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/mayankshukla5031/qL83cf2v/1/)

Working Snippet:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     users: [{firstName: "", lastName: ""}]
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  
  addClick(){
    this.setState(prevState => ({ 
     users: [...prevState.users, { firstName: "", lastName: "" }]
    }))
  }
  
  createUI(){
     return this.state.users.map((el, i) => (
       <div key={i}>
       <input placeholder="First Name" name="firstName" value={el.firstName ||''} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, i)} />
          <input placeholder="Last Name" name="lastName" value={el.lastName ||''} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, i)} />
       <input type='button' value='remove' onClick={this.removeClick.bind(this, i)}/>
       </div>          
     ))
  }
  
  handleChange(i, e) {
     const { name, value } = e.target;
     let users = [...this.state.users];
     users[i] = {...users[i], [name]: value};
     this.setState({ users });
  }
  
  removeClick(i){
     let users = [...this.state.users];
     users.splice(i, 1);
     this.setState({ users });
  }
  
  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + JSON.stringify(this.state.users));
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          {this.createUI()}        
          <input type='button' value='add more' onClick={this.addClick.bind(this)}/>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="container" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
state = {
    number: [""],
    dataArr: []
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div onClick={()=>this.setState(prevState => ({number: [...prevState.number, ""]}))}>Add More element</div>
            {this.state.number.map((e, i)=> {
                return (
                    <input value={this.state.number[i]} onChange={(data) => this.setState({dataArr: update(this.state.dataArr, {i: {$set: data}})})} />
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

You will have to handle the data inside `this.state.dataArr`. For instance, `this.state.dataAtt[0]` will contain the starting value in input field before user presses "Add More Element" button and then when user presses the same button again data will be added in `this.state.dataArr[1]` and so on.

You will need `react-addons-update` lib.