# How to create and store values of multiple inputs in a dynamic form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state, react-functional-component

I have a form where user can generate new inputs to the form he wants to submit, however i am stuck on handling the values of the new generated inputs as i need to store them in the `state`.

**My code**

```
const [supply_detail_data,setSupply_detail_data]=React.useState({
    suppCashDetail:[{text : [],val:[]}]
});

const addNewSuppDetailInput = () => {
    setSupply_detail_data(
        {suppCashDetail: [...supply_detail_data.suppCashDetail,{text : [],val:[]}]}
    )
}

function supply_detail_handler(event){
    // should store the values of inputs in the State
}
```

**JSX**

```
<div className='addNewInput' onClick={addNewSuppDetailInput}>+</div>
 {
    supply_detail_data.suppCashDetail.map((el,index) => {
    let textID='suppDetailText'+index;
    let valID='suppDetailVal'+index;
        return (
        <div key={index}>
        •<input type='text' 
            name={textID}
            value={el.text||''} 
            onChange={supply_detail_handler.bind(index)}
        />

        <input type='number'
            name={valID} 
            value={el||''} 
            onChange={supply_detail_handler.bind(index)}/> 
        </div>
        );

    }) 
 }
```

Each time the user press on the `+` two inputs generated, one of type text the other of type `number`,I need to know how the `supply_detail_handler` that is executed on value change to store the value of new generated `inputs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to assign every input a unique identifier that later you can use in you store. Check this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-firefly-xz31w